# Копирование случайной фразы из списка через кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Есть разметка, выдающая случайную строку из массива при каждом обновлении страницы:

```
<div id="myphrase"></div>


    var div = document.getElementById("myphrase");
    var lst = new Array();
    lst.push("Моя любимая фраза номер один.");
    lst.push("Моя любимая фраза номер два."); 
    lst.push("Моя любимая фраза номер три."); 
    lst.push("..."); 
    lst.push("Моя любимая фраза номер стопицот."); 
    div.innerHTML = lst[Math.floor(Math.random() * lst.length)];
```

Нужно, добавить кнопку копирования этой строки в буфер обмена.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  let text = document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML;
  const copyContent = async () => {
    try {
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
      console.log('Content copied to clipboard');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
    }
  }
```

```html
<p id="myText">Hello World</p>
<button class="btn" onclick="copyContent()">Copy!</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это просто решение копирования текста со страницы через кнопку и оно никак не подтягивает нашу случайную строку из div  id="myphrase"

Comment: const text = document.getElementById('myphrase').innerText;
Или у вас уже возможно нужный текст есть в переменной. Просто вы мало инфы дали в вопросе, конкретно под ваш кейс невозможно дать ответ, т.к. там не конкретики.

Comment: У вас в переменной div вроде нужный элемент лежит, можете использовать эту переменную